# Ajax returning error 401 ("Unauthorized") in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

Newbie here. I have an issue about Ajax. The situation is this: I have a multiselect dropdownlist of managements, and I want to bring the managers from those managements, and attach them on another dropdownlist (I did not finish that).
Here, I call the function and send the selected values:

```
    getManagersByManagement($("#ddlManagement").val());
```

For now, I want this to return the data from GetManagers, on JsonGridDataProvider.svc.

```
    function getManagersByManagement(managementIds) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "../../JsonGridDataProvider.svc/GetManagers",
                data: { 'Id': JSON.stringify(managementIds) },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.jStorage.set($rpt.pageIdentifier + "-Managers", JSON.stringify(data));
                    alert($.jStorage.get($rpt.pageIdentifier + "-Managers"));
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            });
```

This is the GetManagers function >>

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public List<User> GetManagers(long[] managementIds)
        {
            IList<User> allUserList = (new UserBiz()).GetAllByUserByTypeAndState(2, 3);
            List<User> list = (from v in allUserList where v.Active == true orderby v.FullName ascending select v).ToList();
            var finalUserList = (from item in list
                                 let sameManList = (from v in item.Management
                                                    where managementIds.Contains(v.Id)
                                                    select v.Id).Distinct().ToList()
                                 where sameManList.Count > 0
                                 select item).ToList();
            return finalUserList;
        }
```

But when instead of going to the GetManagers function, it returns "error 401" ("Unauthorized"). Any idea why is this happening?

---

***EDIT***

Thank you all for your replies. Thanks to that, I checked **the problem** is not the javascript function nor the ajax configuration, but **the `GetManagers()` function (or some configuration I'm missing).** Any ideas?

Comment: Any permissions issues on the directories, eg "../../JsonGridDataProvider.svc/" ?  Or other server configurations that are expecting authorization on that folder?

Comment: Try `data: JSON.stringify(managementIds) ,`

Comment: test it with absolute url, perhaps you're not hitting the right resource

Comment: also try using post `type: "POST",`

Comment: As a side note: if you are doing RESTful WCF, I'd highly suggest moving to WebAPI.  It's the suggested solution for .NET REST going forward.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172.aspx

Comment: There are some inconsistencies in your code. contentType is set to application/json, however you're only sending GET request vars. your sending data to the server, yet you're using a GET request rather than POST. you're asking jQuery to convert your jsonstring to an object, but you are then immediately converting it back to a jsonstring and never using it as an object.

Comment: I tried changing the url, but nothing happened. So I checked another ajax function previously done that uses the same configuration... didn't work... I thought of commenting the `GetManagers()` function... I commented it, and now it works, so my ajax call is not the problem.
The problem is the GetManagers() function or something related to it. Any suggestions?

I'll edit my question now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an [HttpPost] attribute to the method you are calling. And change the type: "GET" to type: "POST" in your script. Maybe it will help. It worked for me.